# Word count in Texshop

Tags: texshop, word-count

I need to add a word count to my document. The TexShop edit-->statistics option says I have 2793 words, whereas [Texcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/online.php), says I have 3796 words. This is a big difference. Which one should I trust?

Edit: It appears Texcount is correct. There seems to be a bug in texshop, where it doesn't count any words after a \linebreak.

Comment: Welcome! Probably neither is correct ;). What do you need to count exactly? Do you need to include the bibliography? Citations? Material from `\include{}` or `\input{}`? The words in the table or contents, list of figures/tables, glossary or index?

Comment: Well it is pretty straightforward, mostly math and text. I've resolved it now after removing a \linebreak, they both have figures near 4000.

Comment: Both are counting the source. This may or may not be what you need. That's all I meant.

Comment: Since counting the words in TeX/LaTeX code is non-trivial, no automated word count should ever be fully trusted. The main strength of TeXcount is that you can check in detail what is counted by inspecting the verbose output in which details how the different parts of the document have been interpreted.

Comment: Yeah I realize it is only approximate, my problem was that there was a 1000 words difference, which was kind of significant.

Comment: Is the bug fixed now?